# Another way for defining $K_1$ group for a C*-algebra

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, kk-theory

Thank you for answering my question.

I have another question about the $K_1$ group. As you may know, some books define the $K_1$ group like below:

[image]

Also, it defines the $K_0$ group for an arbitrary C*-algebra like below:

[image]

Where $K_{00}(A)$ is the Grothendieck group for the abelian semigroup $V(A)$.

My question is how can I define $K_1(A)$ like the way of $K_0(A)$ more precisely how can I define $K_1(A)$ like below:

[image]

Comment: It seems when we define $K_0$ like above, we add some 0s to the matrices and when we calculate the $Ker$, we nicely remove those 0s.

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: This is how $K_1$ is already defined. Since $K_1(\mathbb C) = 0$ you have $\ker (K_1(A^+) \to K_1(\mathbb C)) = K_1(A^+) = K_1(A)$.